# How would you implement truly random hash functions in practice?

Tags: algorithms, probability-theory, randomized-algorithms, hash, hash-tables

Suppose that $[U] = [0,...,U-1]$ is the universe from which all elements will be taken, and $A$ a hash table of size $m$.

A hash function $h:[U]\rightarrow[m]$ is truly random if

For any set of distincts elements $\{x_{1},...,x_{k}\} \subseteq [U]$ and any set of values $u_{1},...,u_{k} \subseteq [m]$ we have $Pr_{h}[h(x_{1}) = u_{1} \wedge ... \wedge h(x_{k}) = u_{k}] = \frac{1}{m^{k}}$. This of course implies  that $h(x_{i})$ is uniform random and independent of $h(x_{1}),...,h(x_{i-1}),h(x_{i+1}),...,h(x_{k})$.

I was trying to understand why this is not possible to implement efficiently in practice, and found [this paper](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~salil/research/streamhash-Jul07.pdf) where at some point they write in the abstract:

> Hashing is fundamental to many algorithms and data structures widely
>   used in practice. For theoretical analysis of hashing, there have been
>   two main approaches. First, one can assume that the hash function is
>   truly random, mapping each data item independently and uniformly to
>   the range. This idealized model is unrealistic because a truly random
>   hash function **requires an exponential number of bits to describe.**

I do not see how using exponential number of bits can help us come up with a truly random hash function when the universe is $[U]$ and the hash table can store at most $m$ elements.

How would you use an exponential number of bits to come up with a function that can guarantee the probabilities described above?

Comment: A single function cannot guarantee anything; the probability of any event is either 0 or 1. Rather, you want a *distribution* over hash functions, i.e., a *random* hash function chosen according to some law.

Comment: I'm confused about what your question is.  Is your question, a truly random hash function sounds like what I'm looking for, how would I implement something like that in practice?  Or, is your question, why does it require an exponential number of bits to implement a truly random hash function?  The answers to those two will be super-different.  Did Yuval's answer answer your question?

Comment: It was more about why it requires an exponential number of bits to implement such a hash function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of bits required to describe a function from $[U]$ to $[m]$ is $m \times 2^U$. This is exponential in $U$.

Comment: but if I come up with a function h where $h(x) = x$, even though that requires an exponential number of bits, it would not satisfy the probability constraints.

Comment: See my comment to your post. No single function satisfies the probability constraints. The only distribution satisfying them for all $k$ is the uniform distribution over all functions from $[U]$ to $[m]$, and storing a sample from this domain requires $m2^U$ bits.

Comment: Sorry for bringing that up, but what am I missing here? There are $m^U$ functions, so I can store a description with $U\log m$ bits.